# How to run android emulator in AMD devices?

Tags: java, android, eclipse-plugin, amd-processor

It's asking to install Intel haxm plugin but the later works only with Intel processors..Help me in solving this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You do need an Intel processor to use intel haxm. AMD virtualization (AMD-V, SVM) is only supported on Linux.
Some more info:
https://software.intel.com/en-us/android/articles/installation-instructions-for-intel-hardware-accelerated-execution-manager-windows